# llenar combo con los servidores SQL instalados local y remotamente en C#

Tags: c#, sql

Por favor como podría hacer para llenar un combo con los nombres de los servidores SQL Server instalados local y remotamente en C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías utilizar la clase [SqlDataSourceEnumerator](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sql.sqldatasourceenumerator?view=netframework-4.8) la cual te proporciona un método [GetDataSources](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sql.sqldatasourceenumerator.getdatasources?view=netframework-4.8) que puedes utilizar para que te liste todos los servidores de tu red, ojo que se toma su tiempo según indica la **Nota** en la lectura el cual te adjunte en los enlaces, para eso te puedes ayudar de los Thread.

Te muestro un ejemplo sencillo de su aplicacion:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Sql;

namespace ListadoServers
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> m_instance;

            SqlDataSourceEnumerator servidores = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;
            DataTable tablaServidores = servidores.GetDataSources();

            m_instance = new List<string>();

            foreach (DataRow row in tablaServidores.Rows)
            {
                string instanceName = Convert.ToString(row["InstanceName"]);
                string serverName = Convert.ToString(row["ServerName"]);

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(instanceName))
                {
                    m_instance.Add(serverName);
                }
                else
                {
                    m_instance.Add(string.Format("{0}--{1}", serverName, instanceName));
                }
            }

            foreach (var item in m_instance)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Servidor: " + item);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Esto si bien se dilata un poco, te debe funcionar :)

Comment: Buenos días muchas gracias por tu ayuda.. te lo agradezco

Comment: Me funciono perfecto pero solo me busca los servidores SQL instalados en otro equipo de mi red pero si el servidor SQL esta instalado en una maquina local y ejecuto este código n o muestra nada.. porque será amigo...

Comment: Listo ya pude llamar los servidores locales gracias de nuevo amigo